# Custom attributes are missing in HTTP Request Header, But it is present in Shibboleth response

Tags: shibboleth

1) We have created a Custom attribute map(Custom-attribute-map.xml) and placed the file in the shibboleth folder.

```
eg : 
    <Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" id="emailaddress"/>
```

2 )Then we set the path in shibboleth2.xml

```
<AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="Custom-attribute-map.xml"/>
```

So we will get those custom headers in my Application request that comes from Shibboleth .**This is working fine for 2 out of 3 server**.

We have done the same procedure in the 3rd server also but the **custom headers are missing** in 3rd server's **application Request header** (Request.Headers["emailaddress"])

We have checked Shibboleth log, There those custom attributes are available.

```
 <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>UserName@Company.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
```

But those custom headers are not adding into the request header

what can be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Shibboleth usually exposes the attributes as server variables by default, not request headers (that's legacy behavior). 

There's a lot of missing info here... what version of Shib SP? Are you using Apache or IIS? If Apache, do you have `ShibUseHeaders true` set? Do any Shib-related headers appear, i.e. is `Shib-Session-ID` populated? Does the shibd.log indicate that the attributes are being mapped? If the assertion contains them but Shib doesn't like your mapping it won't make them available...

Comment: Hi  Kellen Murphy,

Thanks for the reply ,we are using Apache 

AND

The server,where the header is not working 
   - Shibboleth version : 3.0
   - Shib-Session-ID is not populated

The servers,,where the headers are working
   - Shibboleth version : 2.0
   - Shib-Session-ID is populated

and we are not able to find ShibUseHeaders attribute

Comment: Can you post the <Location> directive you're using from your Apache config that shows the AuthType Shibboleth line? That's where you put ShibUseHeaders On... though I would be negligent if I didn't mention that that's not really a very good idea, and you should instead use environment variables... i.e. instead of Request.Headers["emailaddress"] you'd use something like Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("emailaddress")... exposing attributes in request headers opens you up to attribute spoofing, see: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/SpoofChecking

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the delay in response , because
We raised a ticket to change the shibboleth verssion of from 3 to 2 ( Those working servers are using verssion 2 ) . Hope that will solve the issue .

Note : Shibboleth is using for IIS (Not for appache)

Thank you so much for your support Kellen.

Comment: You might consider spinning up a test environment, and tweaking the application to use Shib 3 with the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable method. Shib 2 isn't practical to keep around for much longer as it's deprecated and will surely pose security concerns at one point or another (though you'd hardly be alone continuing to use it). Just good practice IMHO. Good luck!

Comment: As it is critical issue, we don't have much time to learn and update to 3 .

Comment: As it is critical issue, we don't have much time to learn and update to 3 . once everything become stable we will move to verssion 3 like you suggested

Thank you Kellen